# Catching SIGINT with conditional exit in Python

Tags: python

I want to catch a SIGINT signal in my Python script. However, the script should only terminate if the user enters the correct password after sending the SIGINT. Can this be done in Python? Some sample code to illustrate the problem:

```
import signal

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    password = raw_input("Enter password: ")
    if password != "secret":
        print("Wrong password!")
        # TODO don't let process end
    else:
        print("Password correct. Exiting now.")

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)
```

EDIT: Changed variable 'pass' to 'password', as suggested in the comments below.

Comment: `pass` would not work.

Comment: As suggested by Padraic, you cannot assign `pass` to a variable. And looking at your code, you're using python 3.x, so `raw_input()` has been replaced with simply `input()`. Where is the problem you're facing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can capture the `SIGINT` and dispatch the call off to a function.

e.g.

```
import signal
import sys
import time

def confirm_password(signal, frame, secret="shhh"):
  password = raw_input("Enter password: ")

  if password == secret:
      sys.exit(0)
  else:
      print("Password incorrect.  Refusing to exit.")

while True:
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, confirm_password)
    time.sleep(1000)
```

edit to add code that I've verified to work, not an example from memory :)